# JDK install unique error

Tags: java, installation

So while attempting to install JDK via new task on task manager, it gives me the following error message:

> Unable to install Java
>
> There are errors in the following switches: "(1).exe";
>
> Check that the commands are valid and try again.

I searched for the problem using "There are errors in the following switches" and turned up only one result which didn't help (surprising, considering the internet we live in today). Any and all diagnostic help is much appreciated, I've run out of things to try.

Note: Only this .exe is giving me issues, all other .exe s run fine.

Comment: So are you trying to Run a New Task browsing your java-installer.exe file from Task Manager ? Simple double click on that file will start installing that. Any specific reason for doing it from Task Manager ?

Comment: I tried double clicking, and it did nothing after it prompted me to run it.

Comment: Should I attempt a manual installation?

Comment: What do you mean by manual ?

Comment: Placing files where they need to go. Regardless, I do need to get this problem resolved. Having the JDK is vital to my work.

Comment: Are you trying to install `jdk-8u31-windows-x64.exe` downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) ?

Comment: added quote tags to error message

Answer (score 1):

(The original poster has probably moved on.  This is for people who encounter the same problem and find this Q&A via a Google search.)

The Question does not include enough information to diagnose the problem.  Based on the little that has been provided, I would consider the following:

- Maybe the ".exe" came from a suspect source.  Download it again from the official [Oracle Java download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).  (Don't trust 3rd-party download sites.  They may be serving up an installer that is actually a trojan horse, or loaded up with bloatware...)
- The executable name "(1).exe" is most unusual.  Maybe it is the name that is causing the installer to get confused.  If the name got changed when you downloaded the file, try changing it back to whatever it should be ... or downloading it again.
- You didn't say clearly *how* you tried to run the installer. Maybe you actually did invoke it the wrong way; e.g. with `/(1).exe` as a "switch".

---

> Should I attempt a manual installation?  Placing files where they need to go.

No.  Bad idea.  The installer should work if you have a genuine one and you run it the right way.